# Screen Rotation in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape, viewcontroller, portrait

I need some help regarding "Screen Rotation". I am creating this application in Landscape mode but I also want to be able to turn the iPad to Portrait mode. I am trying something different and making the application inside the viewcontroller. Basically copy and paste a view controller over and over. My issue is that even after I select, "Portrait" to be the ViewControllers Mode it still changed to landscape when i the iPad is turned to Landscape mode. I hope this made sense. Any answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to provide source code of what you've tried. That will help solicit answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the supported orientation modes under the 'Deployment Info' section of your project file in Xcode, might be worth double checking that you are setting the modes for iPad rather than iPhone if you setup your project as a Universal app.